# Make my own "Google Maps" using device location

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

Im on my final project in which I would like to build an android app especifically for the university context. Therefore I would like to use geolocation but for matters of detailed information (colors, shapes, buildings, etc) and gamefication I would like to draw my own map and the user should be able to see his position on this map. So I would have this drawn map and I would use the device's location service and transform the coordinates to a position on my map.

I'm kinda lost on this, didn't find much on the web. So I would apreciate if anyone could point me a direction or if anyone could tell me how hard would it be to implement. Would it be as simple as a function `Point foo (double lat, double lon);`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Drawing the whole map completely would be rather difficult and would involve loads of extra work, thus I would suggest you an alternative that would allow you to have your own drawings, on top of the already made Map.

You could for example use the [groundoverlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/groundoverlay), for items that you want to draw yourself. and then use the google maps under it to show the map, and to handle any positioning etc.